# Could an ELM327 usb to serial interface be used instead of a D+K Can Interface?

Tags: uart, cables

I have an **elm327** 20 pin cable(uart) to usb interface,but it doesnt work with INPA that is a BMW diagnostic software,
I wonder if I could manage to use it as a **D+K Can** with some sort of minor changes.
Since both ELM327 and K DCan cables are doing the same job (uart serial to usb) as far as I know, I guess there should be a way to convert them to each other.(Hypothesis : these cables just do a serial2usb data conversion and nothing more!!, May be the hypothesis is not right)

**ELM327** is an OBD II COMPIANT interface which is based on FT232RL chipset.
[image: ELM327]

**OBD Standard** : Every car company support this standard to deliver diagnostic data to a hardware/software connected to ECUs m, since 1999
[OBD II background](http://www.obdii.com/background.html)

INPA : is a diagnostic software that is specially developed to work with vehicles produced by  BMW company.
Ther is a lot of INPA compatible cables on the market. 
[image: K DCan Cable]

Comment: Please 1) Be specific 2)Post ideas about how you would accomplish this http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I don't know what a "elm327" is (and you haven't provided a link), but if it doesn't "talk CAN" then no this won't work.

Comment: @laptop2d I wish I could, but I have no idea.

Comment: When I say "be specific" write a few paragraphs on what you intend to accomplish, include circuit diagrams and pinouts and links and a block diagram. Then write a few clear questions on about where your having trouble. You listed some acronyms, define them. A professional question will get a professional answer. You say "it doesn't work" can you be more specific? All I'm trying to do is keep your question from getting closed

Comment: @laptop2d Believe me I know how to elaborate a question. Unfortunatly I have a limited knowledge about the subject and also I havn't any sketch or diagram neither studied electrical eng. But those who knows obd II standard and experianced with FT232r chipset will find the question crystal and are able to post an answer. I found nothing about K+D Can cables on the internet to add above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ELM327 allows you to only read/reset generic OBD2 data from any compliant car.

BMW's diagnostic software probably uses a lot of undocumented / undisclosed functions that require more direct access to CAN. You need a dedicated interface.

Comment: Since there is various manufactuer producing KDCan cables, I assume there would be some kind of white paper or diagram that may help me. By the way, what is an ELM327 consist of? Is it just a simple serial to usb board ? or it has some other chipset to support OBD II with some sort of AT command?

Comment: ELM327 [is a factory programmed PIC18F2480](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ELM327). The cable probably also has an FT232 or PL2303 to do UART to USB conversion. If you are really tight on budget then look for dirty cheap K+DCAN cables on Aliexpress.